# Azure deploy failed 'dotnet publish' project file does not exist

Tags: azure, github, deployment, github-actions

I have a .NET API running on Azure that I am attempting to upgrade from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7.0.  When I attempted to deploy my updated .csproj file with the `<TargetFramework>` update and `<PackageReference>` version updates, the deploy to Azure (via push to remote master branch) failed on the `dotnet publish` step.  I recently updated my GitHub action yaml file to update `actions/setup-dotnet@v3` and `actions/checkout@v3` and the jobs section of that file now looks like this

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: '7.x'
        include-prerelease: true

    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: .net-app
        path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

The error I get in Azure is the following

```
Run dotnet publish -c Release -o C:\Program Files\dotnet/myapp
  dotnet publish -c Release -o C:\Program Files\dotnet/myapp
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: C:\Program Files\dotnet
MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: Files\dotnet/myapp
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I am very inexperienced with dev ops and I would be happy to provide more detail if needed.

Comment: You're using NIX-style paths with forward slashes (`/`) on a Windows machine that is expecting backslashes (`\\`). Look at the error message: *Switch: Files\dotnet/myapp*. Also, the statement "The error I get in Azure" is misleading, you aren't doing *anything* with Azure. Your GitHub Action is failing.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you for responding.  I tried replacing the slash with a backslash and it did not seem to solve the problem. Error message now:

```
Run dotnet publish -c Release -o C:\Program Files\dotnet\myapp
  dotnet publish -c Release -o C:\Program Files\dotnet\myapp
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: C:\Program Files\dotnet
MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: Files\dotnet\myapp
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: There is a space in the path. You probably need to escape it by wrapping the path in quotation marks. `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` is a better environment variable as a root output path.

Comment: Changing the variable and adding quotes fixed my problem.  Thank you @DanielMann for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes fixed my problem:

- Change forward slash to backslash on `run` line of `dotnet publish`
- Swap `${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}` with `${{env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}` throughout document
- Surround path with quotes on `run` line of `dotnet publish`

New file partial:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: '7.x'
        include-prerelease: true

    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o "${{env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}\myapp"

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: .net-app
        path: ${{env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}\myapp
```